# Rolling a die - Conditional Probability

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, summation, expected-value, conditional-probability

A die is thrown repeatedly.

Let $X$ ~ First 5 is thrown and $Y$ ~ First 6 is thrown

Calculate $\mathbb{E}(X|Y=3)$

You may use the identity: $\sum_{n=k}^\infty nz^{n-k} = \frac{1}{(1-z)^2}+\frac{k-1}{1-z}$

I know from the definition of expectation, we have:

$\mathbb{E}(X|Y=3) = (1*\frac{1}{5})+(2*\frac{4}{5} * \frac{1}{5}) + (3* \frac{4}{5}* \frac{4}{5} * 0) + (5* \frac{4}{5} * \frac{4}{5} * 1 * \frac{5}{6} * \frac{1}{6}) + (6* \frac{4}{5} * \frac{4}{5} * 1 * \frac{5}{6} * \frac {5}{6} * \frac{1}{6}) + ...$, where every following term, has an extra '$*\frac{5}{6}$' term and constant increases by 1.

However I am unsure of how to apply this to the identity given to find the value of the infinite sum?

Comment: Not sure why you need to work with infinite series at all.  If you fail to see a $5$ by the third toss, then you expect it to take $6$ more tosses to see the first $5$.

Comment: @lulu As in the solution would be $\mathbb{E}(X|Y=3) = (1*\frac{1}{5})+(2*\frac{4}{5} * \frac{1}{5}) + (3* \frac{4}{5}* \frac{4}{5} * 0) + 6$.

Comment: No.  Why $3$ at the end?  I am saying that, if you have reached toss $3$, then the expectation is that you will need $6$ more.  Thus the term should have a $9$ in it, but of course you need to weight that by the probability that you get to the third toss.

Comment: To be clear:  there's nothing wrong with using the infinite series, it's just error prone. Strip out the various constant terms and you are left with a standard Geometric Series.

Comment: @lulu I don't follow? Where did the 9 come from?

Comment: If you have had $3$ tosses (to get to the known $6$) you now expect it to take $6$ more.  $3+6=9$.  Thus, I'd say there are only $3$ possible, expected results.  Either $1,2$ or $9$.  That $9$ of course represents all the paths which take $>3$ tosses.

Comment: But if you find this unintuitive, use the series.  Stripped of the constant terms we just get $\sum_{n=4}^{\infty}  n\times \left(\frac 56\right)^{n-4}$.  Note that your expression omitted the term corresponding to $X=4$ for some reason.

Comment: @lulu, Thanks, I think I get it now. So we have $\mathbb{P}(X=1|Y=3) = \frac{1}{5}, \mathbb{P}(X=2|Y=3) = \frac{4}{25}, \mathbb{P}(X>3|Y=3) = 1-(\frac{1}{5} + \frac{4}{25}) = \frac{16}{25}$. Then we multiply these by the expected results, i.e. 1,2 and 9, giving $\mathbb{E}(X|Y=3) = (1 * \frac{1}{5}) + (2 * \frac{4}{25}) + (9 * \frac{16}{25}) = 6.28$

Comment: Yes, that's what I get.  Note:  it's not a bad idea to check this result against the infinite series.  You can either sum the series (using the hint) or just sum the first $50$ terms or whatever (the tail becomes insignificant rapidly).  The problem, of course, is that series really are error-prone so if you don't get a match, you'll have to  carefully debug the series calculation.

Comment: Note:  if you post your solution below, people can review it (and the system can mark your question as Answered).

Answer (score 2):

$\mathbb{P}(X=1|Y=3)=\frac{1}{5},\mathbb{P}(X=2|Y=3)=\frac{4}{25},\mathbb{P}(X>3|Y=3)=1−(\frac{1}{5}+\frac{4}{25})=\frac{16}{25}.$

Then we multiply these by the expected results, i.e. $1,2$ and $9$, giving $\mathbb{E}(X|Y=3)=(1∗\frac{1}{5})+(2∗\frac{4}{25})+(9∗\frac{16}{25})=6.28$

Comment: (+1) for the computation.  Writing this up for some one else to read, though, you should say some more.  Why is it ok to put the $9$ in for the last term?  I realize we went over this in the comments, but the final write up should not skip big steps.

Answer (score 0):

While it is not necessary, if the question expects you to use the given identity then here is how you would go about it -

$ \small \displaystyle E(X|Y = 3) = 1 \cdot \frac{1}{5} + 2 \cdot \frac{4 \cdot 1}{5^2} + 4 \cdot \frac{4 \cdot 4}{5^2} \cdot \frac{1}{6} + 5 \cdot \frac{4 \cdot 4}{5^2} \cdot \frac{5 \cdot 1}{6^2} + ...$

$ \small \displaystyle  = \frac{13}{25} + \frac{4 \cdot 4}{5^2} \cdot \frac{1}{6} \left (4 \left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^0 + 5 \cdot \left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^1 + ...\right)$

Now note that comparing the below against the given identity,

$ \small \displaystyle 4 \left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^0 + 5 \cdot \left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^1 + ...$

$ \displaystyle \small z = \frac{5}{6}, k = 4$ and $\sum \limits_{n=k}^\infty nz^{n-k} = 54$

and we get, $ \displaystyle \small E(X|Y = 3) = \frac{157}{25}$